# What is the argument to pass to a function that uses custom form request validation as a parameter?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.4

I have a custom validator with a function.
Before the function validates the form info using a custom form request, I have a separate function check a few things.

Below is my code, error is thrown.

Note:
I cannot include the 'stockcancel' code in the 'index' function. They need to run before the validation check, and with form requests, the form request gets run before the actual function code.

Error Message: "Call to a member function call() on null"

```php
public function stockcancel(Request $request, product $product) {


    if ($request->input('submit') == 'cancel') {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    $new = new shipping;

    $this->index($new, $product);

}

public function index(shipping $request, product $product) {


    $validated = $request->validated();

    // .......

}
```

Comment: you can look `withValidator` of form request, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: I'm assuming `shipping` is a custom class, `shipping`, in which case, does this class have the method `validate()` ?